# How to change date format in R from 01-Oct-21 to 02-10-2021

Tags: r, datetime

I have my date column formats in `01-Oct-21` and I want to change them to `01-10-2021`. Does anyone knows how to do this in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R. You might need to convert your original column into Date format using

```
old_date <- as.Date('01-Oct-21', format = '%d-%b-%y')
```

Then you use the `format` function to get into what you what

```
format(old_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

It will look slightly different if your dates are in a data frame.

Comment: df <- as.Date(df$date, format = '%d-%b-%d')

format(df, '%d-%m-%Y'). This is what I tried but not working

Comment: You would want:
`df$date <- format(as.Date(df$date, format = '%d-%b-%y'), '%d-%m-%Y')`

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(lubridate)
format(dmy("01-Oct-21"), '%d-%m-%Y')
[1] "01-10-2021"
```